# Set network tag for Dataflow flex launcher

Tags: java, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

have anyone try to set network tag for their Dataflow Flex Launcher? I am using KafkaIO and required to have a specific network tag to be able to launch the job. I am following https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/routes-firewall#enabling_network_tags_for_flex_template_launcher_vms . However, I could not set new custom tag. The only tag show up on the launcher is dataflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using Flex Templates! The custom tag will not be applied to launcher VM if you use it together with other experiments. The bug fix will be ready in next a few days. Please feel free to follow this thread for latest updates.

Comment: Tks Melody. In my case, I have to add two experiments params because I want to apply network tags to launcher and worker as well. I think it may be the common case for other as well. It would be rare if people only want to apply network on the launcher only. Good to know that it will be fixed soon. It does take me all of the past week to find something working. Btw, no public ips address does not seem to work with launcher as well.

Comment: The experiment is ready to use now. Let me know if you still get problems with the experiments. For the `no public ips` issue, it may require a case-by-case debugging. It is highly recommended to create a support case for that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it is working now. Tks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will use the [projects/{projectId}/templates:launch](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.templates/launch) API from dataflow I have attached the body we are using to add `internet-access` to the network tags of the worker VMs to (in `additionalExperiments` of the `RuntimeEnvironment`):

```
{
  "jobName": "name",
  ...
  "environment": {
    "machineType": "n1-standard-4",
    ...
    "additionalExperiments": ["use_network_tags=internet-access"],
  }
}
```

Comment: your response is only applied network tag on the  worker, not the launcher.

Comment: For the launcher, please use `use_network_tags_for_flex_templates`.